# NativeScript Image Not Working

Tags: html, css, angular, nativescript

In my NativeScript Angular project, I'm trying to add an image to my background and I keep getting an error that's saying

> Value: Error: Response content may not be converted to an Image file

Here's my html where the class is:

```html
<GridLayout class="pageBackground">
  <StackLayout class="main-container">
  </StackLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

and here's my .css where the class is:

```css
.pageBackground{
  background-image: url('https://imgur.com/IjYwn5e');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: i could be mistaken but you need a file type on the end of that url

Comment: @mast3rd3mon oh wow, you're right, I'm an idiot haha. thanks

Comment: i wrote it as an answer so others may find it if they make the same mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use an url as an image in css, the url needs to contain a file type of the image. Eg: `https://imgur.com/IjYwn5e.jpg`

Comment: Can u help me on this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51262183/assertion-failure-and-nsinternalinconsistencyexception-in-nativescript